# Redirecting powershell script output to a file fails

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to redirect the script output to a txt but it fails

```
Clear-Host
$Elementos =Get-WmiObject Win32_Battery -namespace 'root\CIMV2' 
foreach ($Elemento in $Elementos) { 
$Elemento.BatteryStatus 
$Elemento.EstimatedChargeRemaining 
$Elemento.EstimatedRunTime}     >C:\temp\Prueba.txt
```

the result of the script is correct

2

100

71582788

And the resulting error is:

> "The term '>' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
>   script file or executable program. Check if you typed the name
>   correctly, or if a path included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again. Published 7 Character: 2
>   +> <<<< C: \ temp \ Test.txt
>        + CategoryInfo: ObjectNotFound: (>: String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>        + FullyQualifiedErrorId: CommandNotFoundException"

I can't need to say that the path is correct.

If I run for instance:

PowerShell (Get-WmiObject win32_battery).estimatedChargeRemaining > C:\temp\Prueba.txt

that run's OK

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards.

Emilio Sancha
MS Access MVP 2006-2011

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not pipe output of a `ForEach` loop. You can capture it in a variable, or pipe things inside the loop, but you cannot pipe the output of the entire loop in general. There's a couple things you could try...

Capture all output from the loop in a variable, and then output that variable to a file:

```
Clear-Host
$Elementos =Get-WmiObject Win32_Battery -namespace 'root\CIMV2' 
$Output = foreach ($Elemento in $Elementos) { 
    $Elemento.BatteryStatus 
    $Elemento.EstimatedChargeRemaining 
    $Elemento.EstimatedRunTime
}
$Output>C:\temp\Prueba.txt
```

Or you could output inside the loop:

```
Clear-Host
$Elementos =Get-WmiObject Win32_Battery -namespace 'root\CIMV2' 
foreach ($Elemento in $Elementos) { 
    $Elemento.BatteryStatus>>C:\temp\Prueba.txt
    $Elemento.EstimatedChargeRemaining>>C:\temp\Prueba.txt
    $Elemento.EstimatedRunTime>>C:\temp\Prueba.txt
}
```

Or in your case you could just use a `Select` command and output that to a file

```
Clear-Host
$Elementos =Get-WmiObject Win32_Battery -namespace 'root\CIMV2' 
$Elementos | Select BatteryStatus,EstimatedChargeRemaining,EstimatedRunTime | Export-CSV C:\Temp\Prueba.txt -notype
```

Comment: `Export-CSV` might be more appropriate for your last example

Comment: I didn't see the For-Each loop. Good call. So yes, using a variable would be the way to go.

Comment: TheMadTechnician, the first option does not return any errors, nor any data.

The second runs perfectly.

Ami, had already tried with Out-File and had not worked for me.

Thanks to both of you (and sorry my por english).

Kind Regards.

Emilio Sancha MS Access MVP 2006-2011

Comment: Matt, Using Export-CSV I had an other error: No empty pipe elements are allowed.

Answer (score -2):

Use Out-File instead of the caret.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176924.aspx

Comment: While it may be OK advise, it does not solve his problem at all.